# my app crashes when i change the android theme

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mediaplayer, darkmode

i have a music player app, and when i pause the current playing song, return to the MainActivity and change the android theme, it crashes.

i can solve the problem by adding android:configChanges="uiMode" in the manifest, but it's not the behavior that i want, because it prevent the user to change the theme of the app.

this is what shows in the logcat the moment i click to change the theme to when the app crashes:

```
2022-10-15 10:39:18.410  5094-5094  QSControlScrollView     pid-5094                             D  onInterceptTouchEvent 0  return false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.498  5094-5094  QSControlScrollView     pid-5094                             D  onInterceptTouchEvent 1  return false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.500  5094-5094  QSTile.NightModeTile    pid-5094                             D  send click msg
2022-10-15 10:39:18.500  5094-5750  QSTile.NightModeTile    pid-5094                             D  handleClick: from: true, to: false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.511   749-875   SurfaceFlinger          pid-749                              E  Attempt to set layer stack on layer with parent (MiuiColorAnimFade#0) is invalid
2022-10-15 10:39:18.543  2089-2089  SettingsProvider        pid-2089                             V  Notifying for 0: content://settings/secure/ui_night_mode
2022-10-15 10:39:18.544  2089-2089  SettingsProvider        pid-2089                             V  Notifying for 0: content://settings/system/dark_mode_enable
2022-10-15 10:39:18.545  2089-2150  WindowManager           pid-2089                             D  updateContrast : content://settings/system/dark_mode_enable
2022-10-15 10:39:18.545  2089-2150  WindowManager           pid-2089                             I  updateContrastOverlay, darkmode: true isContrastEnabled: false alpha: 0.0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.545 29557-31608 AudioManager            pid-29557                            D  getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.546  2089-2089  SettingsProvider        pid-2089                             V  Notifying for 0: content://settings/system/smart_dark_enable
2022-10-15 10:39:18.546  2089-2117  ActivityTaskManager     pid-2089                             I  Config changes=200 {1.0 724mcc10mnc [pt_BR] ldltr sw392dp w392dp h774dp 440dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 79 - 1080, 2210) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.2799 themeChanged=0 themeChangedFlags=0 extraData = Bundle[{}]}
2022-10-15 10:39:18.548 29557-31608 chatty                  pid-29557                            I  uid=10393(com.tombayley.volumepanel) Binder:29557_6 identical 1 line
2022-10-15 10:39:18.549 29557-31608 AudioManager            pid-29557                            D  getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.552  9879-11237 AiAiEcho                com...onquinn.app.pixelambientmusic  I  Settings changed for uri: content://settings/secure/ui_night_mode
2022-10-15 10:39:18.554 29557-31608 AudioManager            pid-29557                            D  getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.657  2089-2117  ActivityTaskManager     pid-2089                             I  Override config changes=200 {1.0 724mcc10mnc [pt_BR] ldltr sw392dp w392dp h774dp 440dpi nrml long port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2340) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 79 - 1080, 2210) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mDisplayWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined mAlwaysOnTop=undefined mRotation=ROTATION_0} s.2799 themeChanged=0 themeChangedFlags=0 extraData = Bundle[{}]} for displayId=0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.580 29557-31608 chatty                  pid-29557                            I  uid=10393(com.tombayley.volumepanel) Binder:29557_6 identical 9 lines
2022-10-15 10:39:18.581 29557-31608 AudioManager            pid-29557                            D  getStreamVolume isRestricted mode = 0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.695  5518-5518  NotifierManager         pid-5518                             D  maml dark mode 2
2022-10-15 10:39:18.704  4982-4982  TouchInteractionService pid-4982                             D  onConfigurationChanged
2022-10-15 10:39:18.704  4982-4982  TouchInteractionService pid-4982                             D  preloadOverview: mIsUserUnlocked=true   homePackageName=com.mi.android.globallauncher
2022-10-15 10:39:18.748 25002-25002 ocessService0:0         pid-25002                            W  type=1400 audit(0.0:139350): avc: denied { search } for name="theme" dev="dm-1" ino=2228235 scontext=u:r:isolated_app:s0:c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:theme_data_file:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.895  2089-2150  system_server           pid-2089                             W  Long monitor contention with owner Binder:2089_2 (2117) at boolean com.android.server.wm.ActivityTaskManagerService.updateConfiguration(android.content.res.Configuration)(ActivityTaskManagerService.java:4624) waiters=0 in void com.android.server.wm.WindowManagerService.openSurfaceTransaction() for 350ms
2022-10-15 10:39:18.896 25383-25383 ActivityThread          com.example.bloom                    W  SCHED: com.example.bloom/.MainActivity [84, r=557ms, a=103ms, w=2671ms]
2022-10-15 10:39:18.898  5094-5750  BpBinder                pid-5094                             W  Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 398 ms, interface=android.app.IUiModeManager, code=4 oneway=false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.898  5094-5989  BpBinder                pid-5094                             W  Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 355 ms, interface=android.app.IUiModeManager, code=5 oneway=false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.900  5094-5750  QSTile.NightModeTile    pid-5094                             D  night mode changed.
2022-10-15 10:39:18.901  5094-5951  BpBinder                pid-5094                             W  Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 348 ms, interface=android.app.IUiModeManager, code=5 oneway=false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.907  2089-2389  MiuiFreeFo...Controller pid-2089                             D  displayConfigurationChange
2022-10-15 10:39:18.908  2089-2289  FileUtils               pid-2089                             W  Slow Operation: fsync took 161ms
2022-10-15 10:39:18.909  2089-2389  MiuiFreeFo...ntListener pid-2089                             D  updateScreenParams ori:1 mNotchBar:0 mDisplayRotation:0isNotchScreen:true
2022-10-15 10:39:18.909  2089-2389  MiuiFreeFo...Controller pid-2089                             D  displayConfigurationChange
2022-10-15 10:39:18.910  2089-2150  WindowManager           pid-2089                             I   hideContrastOverlay 
2022-10-15 10:39:18.911  2089-2389  MiuiFreeFo...ntListener pid-2089                             D  updateScreenParams ori:1 mNotchBar:0 mDisplayRotation:0isNotchScreen:true
2022-10-15 10:39:18.916  2089-4237  system_server           pid-2089                             W  Long monitor contention with owner Binder:2089_2 (2117) at void com.android.server.UiModeManagerService.setNightModeLocked(int, int)(UiModeManagerService.java:1201) waiters=1 in int com.android.server.UiModeManagerService$12.getNightMode() for 348ms
2022-10-15 10:39:18.917  5094-5094  BpBinder                pid-5094                             W  Slow Binder: BpBinder transact took 370 ms, interface=android.app.IUiModeManager, code=5 oneway=false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.927  2089-4897  MediaFocusControl       pid-2089                             I  abandonAudioFocus() from uid/pid 10392/25383 clientId=android.media.AudioManager@a7203bccom.example.bloom.MusicaKt$$ExternalSyntheticLambda0@24fe664
2022-10-15 10:39:18.929 25383-25383 MediaPlayer             com.example.bloom                    V  resetDrmState:  mDrmInfo=null mDrmProvisioningThread=null mPrepareDrmInProgress=false mActiveDrmScheme=false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.929 25383-25383 MediaPlayer             com.example.bloom                    V  cleanDrmObj: mDrmObj=null mDrmSessionId=null
2022-10-15 10:39:18.929  1365-1660  NuPlayerDriver          pid-1365                             D  reset(0xef95e300) at state 6
2022-10-15 10:39:18.930 10437-10437 TouchAssistant          pid-10437                            D  onReceive action: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED
2022-10-15 10:39:18.930 10437-10437 TouchAssistant          pid-10437                            D  onReceive action: android.intent.action.CONFIGURATION_CHANGED handle completed.
2022-10-15 10:39:18.930  1365-25446 AudioTrack              pid-1365                             V  pause(12172): prior state:STATE_PAUSED
2022-10-15 10:39:18.930  1365-25446 AudioTrack              pid-1365                             V  flush(12172): prior state:STATE_PAUSED
2022-10-15 10:39:18.931  1365-25446 AudioTrack              pid-1365                             V  stop(12172): prior state:STATE_FLUSHED
2022-10-15 10:39:18.931  1365-25446 AudioTrack              pid-1365                             V  ~AudioTrack(12172), releasing session id 62849 from 1365 on behalf of 25383
2022-10-15 10:39:18.932   746-29564 AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  releasing 62849 from 1365 for 25383
2022-10-15 10:39:18.932   746-29564 AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V   decremented refcount to 0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.932   746-29564 AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  purging stale effects
2022-10-15 10:39:18.940  1365-25443 NuPlayerDriver          pid-1365                             D  notifyResetComplete(0xef95e300)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.940   746-969   APM_AudioPolicyManager  pid-746                              D  closeOutput(11925)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.940  1365-1660  AMessage                pid-1365                             W  failed to post message as target looper for handler 0 is gone.
2022-10-15 10:39:18.940  2089-2089  zhoumingliang           pid-2089                             D  isinvrtest==false
2022-10-15 10:39:18.941   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(3: compress-offload-playback) kvpairs: routing=0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.942   746-970   AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  releasing 62849 from 25383 for -1
2022-10-15 10:39:18.942   746-970   AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V   decremented refcount to 0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.942   746-970   AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  purging stale effects
2022-10-15 10:39:18.943   746-968   AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  setParameters(): io 11925, keyvalue closing=true, calling pid 746 calling uid 1041
2022-10-15 10:39:18.943   746-968   AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  setParameters: filtered keyvalue closing=true
2022-10-15 10:39:18.944   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(3: compress-offload-playback) kvpairs: closing=true
2022-10-15 10:39:18.944   746-1207  AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  removeClient_l() pid 25383, calling pid 746
2022-10-15 10:39:18.944   746-969   AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  closeOutput() 11925
2022-10-15 10:39:18.946   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  out_set_parameters: enter: usecase(3: compress-offload-playback) kvpairs: exiting=1
2022-10-15 10:39:18.946   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  copl(0xed0d7800):calling compress flush
2022-10-15 10:39:18.947   697-25448 audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  copl(0xed0d7800):out of compress_wait
2022-10-15 10:39:18.948 25383-25383 m.example.bloo          com.example.bloom                    I  System.exit called, status: 1
2022-10-15 10:39:18.948 25383-25383 AndroidRuntime          com.example.bloom                    I  VM exiting with result code 1, cleanup skipped.
2022-10-15 10:39:18.949   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  copl(0xed0d7800):out of compress flush
2022-10-15 10:39:18.951   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  out_standby: enter: stream (0xed0d7800) usecase(3: compress-offload-playback)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.951   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  copl(0xed0d7800):standby
2022-10-15 10:39:18.988   697-25454 offload_visualizer      pid-697                              D  thread exit
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  disable_audio_route: reset and update mixer path: compress-offload-playback speaker
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  soundtrigger            pid-697                              E  audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: invalid input device 0x0, for event 2
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  soundtrigger            pid-697                              D  audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_stream_status: uc_info->id 3 of type 0 for Event 2, with Raise=1
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  sound_trigger_hal       pid-697                              D  sound_trigger_hw_call_back  event 2 rx_concurrency_active 1, tx_concurrency_active 0, screen on 1, music on 1
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  sound_trigger_hal       pid-697                              D  pcm_transfer_to_barge_in barge in 1, state 0, force idle 0 
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  sound_trigger_hal       pid-697                              D  pcm_transfer_to_barge_in exit barge in 0, state 0, force idle 0 
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  sound_trigger_hal       pid-697                              D  sound_trigger_hw_call_back  rx_concurrency_active 0, tx_concurrency_active 0, screen on 1, music on 0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  msm8974_platform        pid-697                              D  platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(0)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  msm8974_platform        pid-697                              I  platform_get_custom_mtmx_params: no matching param with id 0 ip_ch 2 op_ch 2 uc_id 3 snd_dev 2
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  msm8974_platform        pid-697                              E  platform_get_snd_device_name_extn: device_name=,snd_device=2, device_table[snd_device]=speaker
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  hardware_info           pid-697                              D  hw_info_append_hw_type : device_name = speaker
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  disable_snd_device: snd_device(2: speaker)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.989   697-8020  audio_hw_spkr_dsm       pid-697                              E  audio_extn_spkr_dsm_stop_processing: Entry
2022-10-15 10:39:18.994   697-8020  audio_hw_spkr_dsm       pid-697                              E  audio_extn_spkr_dsm_stop_processing: Exit
2022-10-15 10:39:18.994   697-8020  msm8974_platform        pid-697                              D  platform_split_snd_device: snd_device(2) num devices(0) new_snd_devices(0)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.994   697-8020  soundtrigger            pid-697                              I  audio_extn_sound_trigger_update_device_status: device 0x2 of type 0 for Event 0, with Raise=0
2022-10-15 10:39:18.994   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  audio_enable_asm_bit_width_enforce_mode: DSP bitwidth feature is disabled.
2022-10-15 10:39:18.994   697-8020  audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  out_standby: exit
2022-10-15 10:39:18.995   697-15631 audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  adev_close_output_stream: enter:stream_handle(compress-offload-playback)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.995   697-15631 audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  out_standby: enter: stream (0xed0d7800) usecase(3: compress-offload-playback)
2022-10-15 10:39:18.995   697-15631 audio_hw_primary        pid-697                              D  out_standby: exit
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005  2089-3551  ConnectivityService     pid-2089                             D  ConnectivityService NetworkRequestInfo binderDied(NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=7380, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10392] ], android.os.BinderProxy@fe4e846)
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005   746-1207  AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V  25383 died, releasing its sessions
2022-10-15 10:39:18.998   746-746   Binder:746_A            pid-746                              W  type=1400 audit(0.0:139352): avc: denied { write } for name="logd" dev="tmpfs" ino=534 scontext=u:r:audioserver:s0 tcontext=u:object_r:logd_socket:s0 tclass=sock_file permissive=0
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005   746-1207  AudioFlinger            pid-746                              V   pid 3213 @ 0
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005  2089-2117  MediaSessionService     pid-2089                             D  Media button session is changed to null
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005  2089-2117  MediaSessionStack       pid-2089                             D  Search one active MediaSession due to mMediaButtonSession is null or inactive
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005  2089-2117  MediaSessionStack       pid-2089                             D  Pick the one at tail as mediaButtonSession
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005  2089-2117  MediaSessionService     pid-2089                             D  Media button session is changed to com.android.bluetooth/BluetoothMediaBrowserService (userId=0)
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005  2089-2330  ConnectivityService     pid-2089                             D  releasing NetworkRequest [ TRACK_DEFAULT id=7380, [ Capabilities: INTERNET&NOT_RESTRICTED&TRUSTED Uid: 10392] ] (release request)
2022-10-15 10:39:19.005  2089-6606  MediaFocusControl       pid-2089                             I  AudioFocus  removeFocusStackEntryOnDeath(): removing entry for android.os.BinderProxy@f606a07
2022-10-15 10:39:19.006  2089-2117  ActivityManager         pid-2089                             I  Process com.example.bloom (pid 25383) has died: fore TOP 
2022-10-15 10:39:19.007  2089-2304  InputDispatcher         pid-2089                             W  channel 'b18126f com.example.bloom/com.example.bloom.MainActivity (server)' ~ Consumer closed input channel or an error occurred.  events=0x9
2022-10-15 10:39:19.007   579-579   hwservicemanager        pid-579                              I  getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.iop@2.0::IIop/default in either framework or device manifest.
2022-10-15 10:39:19.007  2089-2304  InputDispatcher         pid-2089                             E  channel 'b18126f com.example.bloom/com.example.bloom.MainActivity (server)' ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!
2022-10-15 10:39:19.007  2089-7412  WindowManager           pid-2089                             I  WIN DEATH: Window{b18126f u0 com.example.bloom/com.example.bloom.MainActivity}
2022-10-15 10:39:19.008  2089-7412  InputDispatcher         pid-2089                             W  Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel 'b18126f com.example.bloom/com.example.bloom.MainActivity (server)'
---------------------------- PROCESS ENDED (25383) for package com.example.bloom ----------------------------
2022-10-15 10:39:19.009  1342-1342  Zygote                  pid-1342                             I  Process 25383 exited cleanly (1)
2022-10-15 10:39:19.012  2089-2162  libprocessgroup         pid-2089                             I  Successfully killed process cgroup uid 10392 pid 25383 in 5ms
2022-10-15 10:39:19.012   579-579   hwservicemanager        pid-579                              I  getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0::IServicetracker/default in either framework or device manifest.
2022-10-15 10:39:19.013  2089-2117  AutoStartManagerService pid-2089                             I  MIUILOG- Reject RestartService packageName :com.example.bloom uid : 10392
2022-10-15 10:39:19.014  2089-2117  ActivityTaskManager     pid-2089                             W  Force removing ActivityRecord{d74f443 u0 com.example.bloom/.MainActivity t1896}: app died, no saved state
2022-10-15 10:39:19.013   579-579   hwservicemanager        pid-579                              I  getTransport: Cannot find entry vendor.qti.hardware.servicetracker@1.0::IServicetracker/default in either framework or device manifest.
2022-10-15 10:39:19.014  8086-19577 BinderSender            pid-8086                             D  onProcessDied: pid=25383, uid=10392
```

Comment: That’s not LogCat. Make sure you’re looking at the Log tab  and not the Run tab.

Comment: @Tenfour04 i added the logcat from the moment it happens the crash

Comment: Something’s filtering out your stack trace in LogCat. You might want to clearing all filters and set it’s level to Error so you don’t get all the unrelated information and it will be easier to find the stack trace.